# How to reduce the space between the end of paragraph and start of title

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I am trying to reduce the space between  the end of paragraph and start of title, but not getting it correctly.

[image]

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have little idea of what you have done. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have done that we can compile and hopefully help you.

Comment: quite likely you have some large unbreakable item on the next page so this page is short but  you have specified `\flushbottom` so latex has to stretch the page out but all section heading code depends on the document class in use and you have given no information.